# Cannot boot Ubuntu from Acer C720 shell

Tags: boot

I'm no longer able to boot Ubuntu from my Acer chromebook. I would be very grateful for any help. I get the following messages in the Shell:

```
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startxfce4
Entering /usr/local/chroots/precise...
[There's a wait of a few minutes before...]
/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot: 453: readlink: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot: 453: mountpoint: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot: 455: readlink: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot: 455: mountpoint: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot: 455: mkdir: Argument list too long
Unmounting /usr/local/chroots/precise...
/usr/local/bin/unmount-chroot: 319: readlink: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/unmount-chroot: 319: mountpoint: Argument list too long
chronos@localhost / $
```

Thank you very much for your help

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and an update fixed it for me.

1. Download the latest version of crouton from https://goo.gl/fd3zc
2. Update via the following command:

   ```
   sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n precise
   ```